# amp-autocomplete: bad results when use remote url

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete, amp-html

Is it possible to cancel previous queries? Or add a delay for autocomplete queries? The issues is that when user quickly types in the search keyword in the field, the queries are sent every time a new character is added and it happens that the first query works longer than the subsequent ones and the results are mixed then. Is there any way to control the sequence?

```
<amp-autocomplete class="amp-autocomplete" filter="none" min-characters="1" src="{{ route('amp.autocomplete') }}" query="clue" on="select:AMP.setState({text: event.value.split('|')[0], url: event.value.split('|')[1]}), searchForm.submit">
    <amp-script layout="container" src="{{ asset('js/amp/autocomplete.js') }}" style="opacity: 1;" sandbox="allow-forms">
        <input id="searchClue" name="clue" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Frage eingeben" value="{{ $clue ?? '' }}" [value]="text" />
        <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-custom">
            <div class="word-item" data-value="@{{text}}|@{{url}}" data-url="@{{url}}">
                <div>@{{text}}</div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <span id="clearSearchButton">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </span>
    </amp-script>
</amp-autocomplete>
```